# Windows 10 IoT / Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: windows-iot, pi-3

Does anyone have any links to information on the planned support / roadmap for **Windows 10 IoT** on Raspberry Pi3?

In particular;

- 64 bit support
- Wifi / Blue tooth drivers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is supported.

There is some information about setup with NOOBS here (open the Pi3 section):

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/Noobs.htm

And a community blog post from Billy Anders, featured here:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/29/windows-10-iot-core-support-for-raspberry-pi-3/

This post is a little light on substance, but suggests that MS are keen to have Windows IoT installed on custom Raspberry hardware produced by element14:

> This morning, the Raspberry Pi Foundation announced availability of
>   their new board—the Raspberry Pi 3. We’re excited to have Windows 10
>   support the new board via a new Windows 10 IoT Core Insider Preview
>   update available for download today.
>
> ...
>
> In the new Insider Preview build available today, we are enabling support for the new Raspberry Pi 3 board and we’re working to bring you more features in the coming weeks.
>
> ...
>
> We are working with element14 to provide customers with the option to choose Windows 10 IoT Core as part of their Raspberry Pi Customization Service. OEMs will now be able to build versions of the Raspberry Pi that meet their unique requirements, use the open source BSP that Microsoft has released and deploy with Windows 10 IoT Core.

Comment: You answer doesn't seem to provide any information on Wi-Fi/ Bluetooth drivers- it isn't supported yet

Answer (score 3):

There is an Insider Preview FFU that you can download and run on your RPI 3.

As things currently stand (build 14262) built-in WiFi definitely isn't supported.  Personal experience of trying this - and couldn't figure out why WiFi wasn't working.

I later found that WiFi and bluetooth support are listed as 'coming soon' (but I can't see a date):

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/WhatsNew.htm

You can still use the supported dongles from before though.

(I'm pretty sure it's still 32bit too!)

Answer (score 2):

You can also download the Windows IoT Insider preview from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot).

Once you download it mount the iso and run the installer. You will get the `.ffu` image file installed under `Program Files/WindowsIoT`

It's straight forward from there.